# Boost shared_ptr: using unique() to implement copy on write

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

Could someone explain what boost [shared_ptr manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) means by this:

> If you are using unique() to implement
>   copy on write, do not rely on a
>   specific value when the stored pointer
>   is zero.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, I can see the definition of copy on write (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) but not totally sure how this applies here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy-on-write is a storage scheme where copies of an object with duplicate values are represented by a single object. Only when you try to change one is it copied to a new, unique object.

Boost supports this by telling you whether a given `shared_ptr` is supporting more than one reference. If it is, then writing to the object will require making a copy.

The manual is saying that if you have NULL pointers in such a scheme, they might report being either unique or not. Really, Boost is being generous by even allowing such an operation.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what it means is that if you have a `shared_ptr` that doesn't point to anything, it might or might not say that it is unique. However, you should know that COW has been ditched by almost all major string libraries and disallowed for C++0x because it sucks, basically, so you want to be careful about doing this.

Comment: P.J. Plauger can and will attest this, however likely in much less strong wordings :)

Comment: It sucks for string libraries; there are still other good applications.